Error 404 when I try to login to my React project
I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to log in to my web application, but I'm unable to pinpoint the issue. I've provided relevant code snippets below for reference:
enter image description here
Context:
I have a web application where users can log in, and I'm currently facing an issue with the login functionality. When I attempt to log in, I receive a 404 error, indicating that the requested resource was not found. However, I've double-checked my code and configurations and can't seem to identify what's causing the problem.
Code Snippets:
auth.routes.js: This file defines the routes related to authentication.
auth.js: Here, I've included functions for making requests related to authentication, such as logging in and verifying tokens.
axios.js: This file configures Axios, a popular HTTP client, to communicate with my backend API.
app.js: This is the main entry point of my Express application, where I configure middleware and route handling.
App.jsx: In this React component, I've set up routing for different pages of my application, including the login page.
auth.controller.js: This controller handles the logic for user authentication, including verifying credentials and generating tokens.
Additional Information:
Backend Route: My backend server is running on http://localhost:4000.
Frontend Route: The frontend of my application is accessible via http://localhost:5173.
Despite thorough debugging efforts, I'm still unable to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing the 404 error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!
I leave you below my code.
auth.routes.js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { login, logout, profile, verifyToken } from '../controllers/auth.controller.js'
import { authRequired } from '../middlewares/validateToken.js'
import { validateSchema } from '../middlewares/validator.middleware.js'
import { loginSchema } from '../schemas/auth.schema.js'

const router = Router()

router.post('/login', validateSchema(loginSchema), login)
router.post('/logout', logout)
router.get("/profile", authRequired, profile)
router.get("/verify", verifyToken)

export default router

auth.js
import axios from './axios.js';

export const loginRequest = user => {
    return axios.post('/login', user)
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error al realizar la solicitud POST:", error);
            throw error; // Propaga el error para que pueda ser manejado en el componente que llama a loginRequest
        });
};

export const verifyTokenRequest = () => axios.get('/api/verify');


axios.js
import axios from 'axios';

axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
    withCredentials: true
});

export default axios;

app.js
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";

import authRoutes from './routes/auth.routes.js'
import auditoriaRoutes from './routes/auditoria.routes.js'

const app = express()

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    credentials: true
}))
app.use(morgan("dev"))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use('/api', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', auditoriaRoutes);

export default app

App.jsx
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './context/AuthContext.jsx';

import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import AuditoriaPage from './pages/AuditoriaPage';
import ProfilePage from './pages/ProfilePage';

import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />} >
            <Route path='/auditoria' element={<AuditoriaPage />} />
            <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfilePage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter >
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

auth.controller.js
import User from '../models/user.model.js'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { createAccessToken } from '../libs/jwt.js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { TOKEN_SECRET } from '../config.js'

export const login = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        console.log("Solicitud de inicio de sesión recibida:", email); // Agregar registro de depuración
        const userFound = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!userFound) {
            console.log("Usuario no encontrado:", email); // Agregar registro de depuración
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "User not found" });
        }

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userFound.password);
        if (!isMatch) {
            console.log("Contraseña incorrecta para el usuario:", email); // Agregar registro de depuración
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Incorrect email or password" });
        }

        console.log("Inicio de sesión exitoso para el usuario:", email); // Agregar registro de depuración
        const token = await createAccessToken({ id: userFound._id });
        res.cookie('token', token);
        res.json({
            id: userFound._id,
            username: userFound.username,
            email: userFound.email,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error en la función de inicio de sesión:", error); // Agregar registro de error
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
}


Have you checked to make sure the ports are actually open using netstat? Are you sure you are going to http and not https?

Seems like you are using two routes with the same name. Can you try keeping only the required auth one in app.js?
Also if both are required, they should have separate routes. Since the api won't know which one to hit.
app.use('/api', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', auditoriaRoutes);

